# How to set multiple span for recycler gridview and show header and footer

Tags: android, gridview, android-recyclerview

I have a fragment listing couple of items from an array where array is filled from a API, Also I have created a fragment class and a recycler adapter where I had called Layout manager as grid view. my view have a header contains two item of array and a footer of ad. I successfully implemented the header but am not getting my footer properly. suggested ways are valuable without a major change.

Fragment

```
  mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.mrecycler_channel);
        mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        GridLayoutManager gm = new GridLayoutManager(getActivity(),2);
        gm.setSpanSizeLookup(new GridLayoutManager.SpanSizeLookup() {
            @Override
            public int getSpanSize(int position) {
                return position == 0 ? 2:1;
            }
        });
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(gm);
        mAdapter = new StationsListAdapter(getActivity(), listStations, listlikedStations, listner);
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
```

recyclerview Adapter

```
      @Override
        public int getItemCount() {
        int array = listAddress.size();
            Log.d("abhil",""+array);
    //        if(listAddress.size()>0) {
                return listAddress.size() - 1;
    //        }else{
    //            return 0;
    //        }
        }

        @Override
        public int getItemViewType(int position) {
            if (position == 0) {
                return TYPE_HEADER;
            } else if(isPositionFooter(position)){
                return AD_TYPE;
            }
            return TYPE_ITEM;
        }
 private boolean isPositionFooter (int position) {
        return position == listAddress.size() + 1;
    }
```

need to set ad on last position as a normal banner ad showing in Recyclerlistview.

Answer (score 1):

You could achieve it like this:

```
gm.setSpanSizeLookup(new GridLayoutManager.SpanSizeLookup() {
        @Override
        public int getSpanSize(int position) {
            //Do your lookup here

            return (position == 0 || position == listStations.size() - 1) ? 2 : 1;
        }
    });
```

Comment: || operator cant be used in int and boolean

Comment: actually i have 3 item one header, list item and finally at footer i want to add an ad 
i've tried the code but my footer ad is not showing up

Comment: your footer is not showing up because in getItemCount() method you are returning "listAddress.size() - 1". You should return "listAddress.size() + 1", which is basically "listAddress.size() - 1" + 1 for the header and + 1 for the footer

Comment: @Gustavo Not + 1 it should be + 2 currently it works fine for me. because my list is inflating 14 items where 2 items are taken in header and counted as one .so the total array count will be 13 , so I should add 2 item so that i can span position 14 and 15 to one and can show ad on that perticular position.